# Convergence of delta function

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I have a physical quantity of a disordered system. Based on numerical analysis, the distribution of this quantity over random disorder realizations seems to be Gaussian. The value of this quantity decreases as the size L of the system increases. As L increases, the mean of this quantity goes to zero faster than its standard deviation. Can one still say that the distribution of this quantity converges to a delta function as L goes to infinity?